# AEM DAM apect ratio crop

Tags: aem, assets, crop, dam

[DAM editing snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE5d9.png)
I need to add some more fixed aspect ratio cropping shapes to my AEM 6 SP3 DAM editor (e.g. 4:3, 3:4, 9:16). There need to be a configuration option, but a cannot find something to customize this. Maybe someone of you guys have had the same problem as me and can tell me about the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem. If you want to have custom aspect ratio in your crop options drop down, you just need to overwrite the 
/etc/clientlibs/granite/coralui2/optional/imageeditor/js/cui-imageeditor.js in your project. The options for the drop down are hardcoded in this js file. [see custom crop options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFzhB.png)

The next problem will come with an update to AEM 6.1. The file cui-imageeditor.js wont exist anymore. Just a dummy file will appear in the same directory...
[dummy file am 6.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hELgP.png)

Comment: There is another post that discusses how to do it in AEM 6.3 here, https://forums.adobe.com/message/9868589

Comment: Thanks @CrisRockwell I will check that out.